# Permission Denied in ie11 trying to access the options of a select in another frame

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have a legacy app with a bunch of frames.  They are all loaded from the same domain.  This bit of code works in Chrome and Edge.  It worked in IE with compatibility mode on to IE9, but doesn't work in IE11 with compatibility mode off.  I get "Permission Denied".

```
var par = parent.sidebar.document.theSideBar;
var assetListArray = par.assetList.options;
for (var k=0; k < assetListArray.length; k++) {
    if (assetListArray[k].value == currentAsset) { //blows up on this line
        inList = true;
        assetListArray[k].selected = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

In the debugger if I try to see par.assetList's options I get permission denied.  But I CAN see them through it's innerHTML.  So I suppose that if I wrote alot of string parsing, I could get around this.  But while par.assetList is in another frame, it's the same domain (I confirmed that by examining the document.domain and parent.sidebar.document.domain).

Note that these are frames, not iframes. If that matters.

Comment: As you had mentioned that the frames are loaded from the same domain. Here I want to confirm with you, whether there is any difference in the path, protocol, port, host of the URLs for the frames? or everything the same? If possible, try to add the site to the Trusted site list and see whether it help to fix the error. If possible then I suggest you post the snapshot of the error. I suggest you try to provide us the detailed steps with the sample code to reproduce the issue. It can help to check the result and narrow down the issue.

Comment: protocol, port, host are all the same. Path is different.  They all come from the same EAR, so the start of the path is the same, but some are jsps, some servlet calls.  I can't do the trusted thing.  This is an intranet site in a govt environment and the security team has that option locked down.

Comment: If it is possible for you then I suggest just for the testing purposes try to lower down the Security level for the internet or intranet zone and see whether it makes any difference. If it helps to suppress the error then further you need to make a test with each option in the zone to find the option that is causing this issue. If you can provide the steps and sample code then it can help to understand the issue in a better way.